# Textbox "locks" when value is null (integer is expected)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, textbox, sql-server-ce

i'm working in a c# windows application with vs2010 and a local database.In one of my forms,  I'm using a bindingNavigator and i have inserted some Textboxes where some of those need to be filled with integers only.

The problem is that when i'm deleting all data inside from one of those textboxes, mouse is locked and i cannot move to another textbox or shut down the programm unless at least one number is inserted in the textbox. How can i make it autocomplete itself with 0 when nothing is inserted and be able to continue to navigate into the programm?

Comment: 99.99% of the time on SO, code is needed to help answer questions.

Comment: can i use something like this: int test = 0; if(textbox1.Text==null){textbox1.Text = test.ToString();} and in which event?

Comment: The solution was simple really, the problem was in the textbox.Text==null expression.

In the Leave event of the textbox i just used the code: 

           if (nameTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                nameTextBox.Text = "0";
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple really, the problem was in the textbox.Text==null expression. In the Leave event of the textbox i just used the code:

```
if (nameTextBox.Text == "") 
{ 
nameTextBox.Text = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have many such controls, it's boring to write this conditions for every control. You may just inherit TextBox control:

```
public partial class NumberTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public NumberTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NumberTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tTxt = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
            double tDbl;
            int tInt;
            if (tTxt == "" || !double.TryParse(tTxt, out tDbl) || !int.TryParse(tTxt, out tInt))
            {
                ((TextBox)sender).Text = "0";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you found a solution, but you really want to use:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameTextBox.Text)){ nameTextBox.Text = "0"; }
```

to fill in a zero, and after that use int.TryParse instead on int.Parse:

```
int n;
if(!int.TryParse(nameTextBox.Text, out n))
{
//handle failed parse
}
...
```

this way you will avoid possible exceptions when an integer conversion is impossible(f.e. a letter is entered)